# how to add notification bar under header

Tags: css

First of all i am new to css and i want a black notification bar right under header for free shipping, and the text will be white. This should be full width to browsers

i tried to do it with css and heade::after but my text stays on left corner and can not be centered

```
header::after {
  content: "test test text";
    margin: 0 -9999rem;
  /* add back negative margin value */
  padding: 0.25rem 9999rem;
  background: #101010;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first and then read [ask]. After that edit your question accordingly and add a [repro] for debugging details. Note that CSS alone is not helpful in most cases.

Comment: PS: to center text you could simply add `text-align: center` to the pseudo-element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the reason for those weird paddings and margins but simply `text-align:center` along with `display:block` should work.

```css
header::after {
  content: "test test text";
   margin: 0 -9999rem;
  /* add back negative margin value */
  padding: 0.25rem 9999rem;
  background: #101010;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align:center;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<header>I am header</header>
```

Comment: Remove those margins. Make sure you added also `display:block` and also by inspecting element and checking the calculated CSS rules, make sure there is not an overriding rule like `*{text-align:left}` @ΠΑΝΑΓΙΩΤΗΣ

Comment: thanks it worked perfectly. those weird paddings and margins were for full width. should i do it with another way ?

Comment: For full width `display:block` is enough. @ΠΑΝΑΓΙΩΤΗΣ